# how to print a screen capture in wpf

Tags: wpf, printing, screen, capture

first I don't speak English fluently.
Anyway.
I'm trying to do this.
However it does not third day.
I'm doing now is program screen print after screen capture.
I refer to this code.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0623964c-4bb4-44c0-a1cb-4dbb2fa161f0/need-simple-c-code-to-print-a-screen-capture?forum=winforms

but this only for winform.
I tried to be tried the same from wpf with that.
I want to auto fit to page.
Here is my code

```
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
    void bt1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var cv = sender as Canvas;
        var btName = cv.Name;

        if (btName.Contains("8"))
        {
            MakeScreenshot();

            PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();


            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

            pd.PrintPage += printPage;

            if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                pd.Print();
            }
        }
    }




    public System.Windows.Point Location
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Windows.Point(Left, Top);
        }
        set
        {
            Left = value.X;
            Top = value.Y;
        }
    }



    public void MakeScreenshot()
    {             
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);

        FrameworkElement pnlClient = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
        double dWidth = -1;
        double dHeight = -1;

        if (pnlClient != null)
        {
            dWidth = pnlClient.ActualWidth;
            dHeight = pnlClient.ActualHeight;
        }

        var desktop = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        this.Left = desktop.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = desktop.Bottom - this.Height;


        bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap((int)dWidth, (int)dHeight, g);
        var memoryGrphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
        memoryGrphics.CopyFromScreen((int)this.Location.X, (int)this.Location.Y, 0, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

       }           
        bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    }

    private void printPage(object sender,System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpScreenshot, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is capture the screen shot as a Bitmap using System.Drawing i.e Winforms way,then convert the captured bitmap to BitmapSource image.

```
private static BitmapSource CopyScreen()
{
    using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(
       (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth,
        (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight,
       PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
  {
       using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
        {
        bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenBmp.Size);
        return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            screenBmp.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
   }
 }
```

You will need add a reference to System.Drawing, and the following namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

After the screen is being converted as BitmapSource you print the same.

Image Control xaml

```
    <Image Name='imageCapture' Stretch='UniformToFill'/>

            ///Print Screen shot code

            PrintDialog imgControlPrint = new PrintDialog();
            ///img Control wpf
            imageCapture.Source=CopyScreen();
            if ((bool)imgControlPrint.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                imageCapture.Measure(new Size(imgControlPrint.PrintableAreaWidth,imgControlPrint.PrintableAreaHeight));
                imageCapture.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), imageCapture.DesiredSize));
                imgControlPrint.PrintVisual(imageCapture, "Screen Shot");
            }
```

Comment: I have a question.
imageCapture.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), imgControlWpf.DesiredSize));
What is a "imagControlWpf"?

Comment: @Juyoung srry it should be "imageCapture". Edited the post!